# Is it possible to install Alfresco and Canvas LMS on the same server using Bitnami?

Tags: alfresco, bitnami

I've read about Bitnami modules using LAMP and Ruby, etc. But I would like to know if it is possible to install both Alfresco and Canvas LMS on the same server?

Since they're full installers and not modules, is this currently possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here.

Yes, you can. You will need to use the Bitnami installers (not the modules, we don't provide modules for those applications) to install both applications in the same server as they require different components to run. They will use different ports when running and the installers will ask you to set a different one when the default one is in use.